# How to mock antd useFormInstance?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, antd

I need to mock form instance for test `!form?.isFieldsTouched()` case
don't advise to provide the form as a prop, please.

this is my component:

```
export const OCRActions = ({ isEditDisabled, set }: IOCRActionsProps) => {
  const form = useFormInstance();

  return (
    <Item
      noStyle
      shouldUpdate
    >
      {() => (
        <Group>
          <Popconfirm
            title={(
              <div className='w-[200px]'>
                Do you want to apply made changes?
                Note that they may result in receipt reprocessing.
              </div>
            )}
            okText='Yes'
            cancelText='No'
            placement='bottom'
            onConfirm={handlePatchOCR(form, ocrFormValues, patchSnapsDetails)}
            disabled={
              !form?.isFieldsTouched()
            }
          >
            <Button
              type='primary'
              loading={loading}
              disabled={
                !form?.isFieldsTouched()
              }
            >
              Save
            </Button>
          </Popconfirm>
        </Group>
      )}
    </Item>
  );
};
```

I have tried to mock in this way, but didn't help for me, call useFormInstance() return undefined, also I used GPT...

```
jest.mock('antd', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('antd');

  return {
    ...originalModule,
    Form: {
      ...originalModule.Form,
      useFormInstance: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({
        getFieldsError: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(() => []),
        isFieldsTouched: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(true),
      }),
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mock the `useFormInstance()` hook, it will break its function. Instead, we need some auxiliary components for testing `<OCRActions/>` component. You can create a test component that renders the `<Form/>` component and a simple `<Input/>` component. Change the value of the input, then check if the button is disabled.

e.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'antd';

const { useFormInstance, Item } = Form;
export const OCRActions = () => {
  const form = useFormInstance();

  return (
    <Item noStyle shouldUpdate>
      {() => (
        <Button type="primary" disabled={!form?.isFieldsTouched()}>
          Save
        </Button>
      )}
    </Item>
  );
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { Form, Input } from 'antd';
import { OCRActions } from '.';

describe('78048690', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const TestContainer = () => {
      const [form] = Form.useForm();

      return (
        <Form form={form}>
          <Form.Item name="username">
            <Input placeholder="Username" />
          </Form.Item>
          <OCRActions />
        </Form>
      );
    };
    render(<TestContainer />);

    const button = screen.getByRole('button');
    expect(button).toBeDisabled();
    fireEvent.change(screen.getByPlaceholderText('Username'), { target: { value: 'mrdulin' } });
    expect(button).toBeEnabled();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/78048690/index.test.tsx                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  78048690
    √ should pass (290 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------                                                                                                                                                                          
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s                                                                                                                                                                           
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 | 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.947 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
"antd": "^5.14.2",
```